# Node Keycloak requests returns Login even with bearer token

Tags: javascript, node.js, keycloak, keycloak-connect, keycloak-nodejs-connect

I've been trying to integrate Keycloak into a simple node/express server so that I can authenticate with a bearer token in the header, but every protected request I'm making returns html(login page).

My simple index.js file:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const keycloak = require('./kc-config.js').initKeycloak();

app.use(keycloak.middleware());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send("Server is up!");
});

app.get('/kc-test', keycloak.protect(), (req, res) => {
  res.send('success');
} )

app.listen(3000);
```

My simple kc-config.js file

```js
var session = require('express-session');
var Keycloak = require('keycloak-connect');

let _keycloak;
var keycloakConfig = {
  clientId: 'myclient',
  bearerOnly: false,
  serverUrl: 'http://my.client.com:4008/auth',
  realm: 'master',
  credentials: {
    "secret": "{my-secret}"
  }
};

function initKeycloak() {
  if (_keycloak) {
    console.warn("Trying to init Keycloak again!");
    return _keycloak;
  }
  else {
    console.log("Initializing Keycloak...");
    memoryStore = new session.MemoryStore();
    _keycloak = new Keycloak({ store: memoryStore }, keycloakConfig);
    return _keycloak;
  }
}

function getKeycloak() {
  if (!_keycloak){
    console.error('Keycloak has not been initialized. Please called init first.');
  }
  return _keycloak;
}

module.exports = {
  initKeycloak,
};
```

I am using the token returned from this curl request:

```js
curl -X POST 'http://my.client.com:4008/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token'
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password'
--data-urlencode 'client_id=myclient'
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=mysecretkey'
--data-urlencode 'username=myusername'
--data-urlencode 'password=mypassword'
```

Shouldn't I be authorized? Why would it ask me to login again even though my token is valid?

For more information, here's a screenshot of my settings for my client, on the keycloak admin console.

[image: Client Keycloak Settings]

I'm pretty confused. Am I using it completely wrong? My thought process was that I would be able to simply put the token from the curl request into the header of the request for the protected /kc-test route.

Comment: The "Access Type" of your client is set to "public" yet you're using a client secret? The public clients do not have a client secret.

Comment: The same result happens if I change it to "confidential".

Answer (score 0):

Access type of the client need to be bearer only.

```
{
  "realm": "camunda",
  "auth-server-url": "https://localhost:9000/auth/",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "user-management",
  "bearer_only":true,
  "credentials": {
    "secret": "45078604-3c4a-44a6-8a0f-ab094f050211"
  },
  "confidential-port": 0,
  "policy-enforcer": {}
}
```

or you can set the bearer_only to true in you keycloak.json file

Answer (score 0):

When you change the Access Type to "Bearer Only" in the settings of your client, you will get a nice 403. Keep in mind that this will not allow any requests without a valid bearer token (like obtaining the token itself).

The alternative is setting Access Type to "confidential" in the settings of your client and setting `"bearerOnly": true` in your `keycloak.json` (or keycloakConfig in your case).